# How to ground with two sources of power and an unknown output voltage

Tags: power, ground, grounding, stepper-motor

Hi I have a setup that I'm really going to simplify:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwjW1R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have two questions about this setup:

1. Why do I only measure 3V volts across the ground wire when I put 5 in?
2. Is this proper grounding? I had issues before with this and the motor is definitely not getting the power it needs. I know its not an issue with the power supply because I got this power supply to work before, I just forgot how. I strongly suspect something is not grounded right.

Comment: As it is now, the 12V and 5V supplies are shorted together. Please don't simplify, show the whole circuit.

Comment: @Justme Will fix it

Comment: Also, when you say you " measure 3V volts across the ground wire " please show the two points you're measuring.

Comment: @ErikR I put my multimeter between the GND of the motor driver and the 3 wries junction at the ottom

Comment: @Justme schematic had been fixed, is this detailed enough?

Comment: " I put 17 in and only take 12 out" -- the 5V from the Arduino doesn't go to power the motor. Only the 12V supply is used to power the motor.

Comment: @ErikR so how does the 5V get grounded?

Comment: They way you drawn things both the Arduino and 12V supply share the same ground reference.

Comment: @ErikR Is that a bad thing? Why?

Comment: No - it's usually the way you do things.

Comment: Oh okay, But if I'm putting 5V in why am I only getting 3Vish out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126150/discussion-between-erikr-and-kidwithcomputer).